# Aggregate a variable using two grouping variables within a function in R

Tags: r, function, aggregate

I am trying to write a function which will give me simple descriptive statistics of a population by age and country.

Here is an example of my data:

```
popcount = 200:250
sex = rep(c("M", "F"), 25)
country = rep(c("NZ", "Aus", "Fiji", "PNG", "Samoa"), 10)
```

To get the aggregation, I have specified the following function

```
Aggregate_fun <- function(pop, ag1, ag2) {
popbylist <- data.frame(aggregate(pop, by = list(ag1, ag2)), FUN=sum)
return(popbylist)
}
```

Then I run this function on my data

```
Gend_Country <- Aggregate_fun(pop = popcount, ag1 = sex, ag2 = country)
```

When I run this, I get the following error message:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
>
> 6.
>   match.fun(FUN) 
>   5.
>   aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) 
>   4.
>   aggregate.default(pop, by = list(ag1, ag2)) 
>   3.
>   aggregate(pop, by = list(ag1, ag2)) 
>   2.
>   data.frame(aggregate(pop, by = list(ag1, ag2)), FUN = sum) 
>   1.
>   Aggregate_fun(pop = popcount, ag1 = sex, ag2 = country)

I know there's an error with the way I am specifying the list of variables to aggregate by. I've tried a number of different things to fix this, but none of them work. Does anyone know how to write this function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a parenthesis is misplaced in that aggregate function placing the "FUN" outside of aggregate.  Additionally popcount had 51 values while the other two only had 50.  This code below is doing what I think you desire.

```
popcount = 201:250
sex = rep(c("M", "F"), 25)
country = rep(c("NZ", "Aus", "Fiji", "PNG", "Samoa"), 10)

Aggregate_fun <- function(pop, ag1, ag2) {
  popbylist <- data.frame(aggregate(pop, by = list(ag1, ag2), FUN=sum))
  return(popbylist)
}

Gend_Country <- Aggregate_fun(pop = popcount, ag1 = sex, ag2 = country)
```